# APNS Certificates on Ubuntu

Tags: ios, ubuntu, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I read this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

He is generating the certificate signing request on his Mac using Keychain Access:

[image]

For Production, we are using an Ubuntu Server. Do you have to generate the CSR on the Ubuntu Server directly, or can you use the certificate generated on my Mac?

[image]

If you have to generate the CSR on the Ubuntu server, how can this be done?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Comment: Which stackexchange would suit better? serverfault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSR generated on the Mac.  Once you have the signed certificates (one for development and one for production) from the Apple Developer portal you will need to export them (including the private key) for use on your server, as per your second screen shot.